# (HTML) add a variable onto current URL

Tags: html, widget

An easy one for you, to help a non-programmer.

I'm a web designer helping out a Magento Go store owner.  Their website displays in English or in German.  The widget which controls language makes the change by adding two variables onto the current URL:

```
?___store=default&___from_store=german (to change from German to English)
?___store=german&___from_store=default (to change from English to German)
```

I've added two PNG country flags at the top of the page, and I want a click on either of these flags to add the appropriate variables above to be added to the current URL.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="?___store=default&___from_store=german"><img src="german.png" /></a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:window.location+='?___store=default&___from_store=german'"><img src="german.png" /></a>
```

But this is a Magento deployment, the store switcher should be doing fine by itself.

Comment: Simple.  Thank you Mihai.  (the store owner wanted the flags for some reason)

Comment: In Magento 1.7 there's a store-switcher template defined specifically for flags. So basically all you needed to do was to change the layout XML that added the store switcher from using the `language.phtml` or `stores.phtml` templates to using this template: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/flags.phtml`

Comment: As a rule of thumb you should state your "end goal" first, document what you have tried and only then ask a question that solves your "apparent goal". Some solutions will likely be better by circumventing your "apparent goal" but still solving your "end goal".

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript:

```
<img src = "yourgermanflagimg" onclick = "changeURL('german')" alt = "german flag">
<img src = "yourenglishflagimg" onclick = "changeURL('english')" alt = "german flag">

<script type = "text/javascript">
function changeURL(type)
{
if(type=="german")
{
window.location.assign("www.yourpage.com?___store=default&___from_store=german");
}
else
{
window.location.assign("www.yourpage.com?___store=default&___from_store=default");
}
</script>
```

Comment: The solution should **add** the parameters to the current URL. If you use a fixed prefix ('yourpage.com') you'd get redirected to the homepage every time you changed the language.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I got the impression that the OP wanted to reload his current page in a different language. I prefixed it because I don't know the real name of his page.

Comment: Those URLs are typical for Magento "store" switchers. Stores have an associated language. Hence it is (indeed) a language switcher. But it is meant to switch any page to its translated version.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I see. Sorry. I don't know how to get the URL in JavaScript, but my answer stil stands.